# calling back end only for particular component in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have Tags Components in my project and I reused that component in other components. In my Tags component ngOnInit, I called backend to get all the existing tags. The problem I have right now is that call is applied to every other components even though the call is not needed at other components other than Edit Components. Since I only need the backend call to show existing tags just for Edit Components, I tried to move that call to Edit Components ngOninit but it didn't show me the existing tags anymore. I would be really appreciated if I can get any help or suggestion on how to fix this.

Tags Component TS

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.tagService.getAllTagsByType('user').subscribe((normalTags) => {
      this.loading = true;
      if (normalTags)
        this.allnormalTags = normalTags;
      this.allnormalTags.forEach(normalTags => {
        this.allTagNames.push(normalTags.tag);
      });
      this.loading = false;

    })
  }
```

If i add this call in Tags Component, it show me all the existing tags in drop down. I tried to move this to Edit component ngOnIt since I only want Eidt Component to use that call but It didn't show me existing tags anymore.

Tags.Service.ts

```
  getAllTagsByType(tagType: any){
    return this.http.get<Tag[]>(`${environment.api.chart}/tags/all/${tagType}`).pipe(first());
  }
```

Comment: What is tagService? share inside it in question also

Comment: hi, TagsService is is an API call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to setup a flag to trigger the backend call using [`@Input`](https://angular.io/api/core/Input).

tags.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

export class TagsComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() getAllTags = false;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (this.getAllTags) {         // <-- check here
      this.tagService.getAllTagsByType('user').subscribe(
        (normalTags) => {
          this.loading = true;
          if (normalTags)
            this.allnormalTags = normalTags;
            this.allnormalTags.forEach(normalTags => {
              this.allTagNames.push(normalTags.tag);
            });
          this.loading = false;
        },
        error => {
          // handle error
        }
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Now pass the value `true` to `getAllTags` when you wish to make the backend call. Since `ngOnChanges` hook is triggered before `ngOnInit`, the call will not be made if the property isn't passed in the component selector.

```html
<!-- edit component -->
<mc-tags 
  [getAllTags]="true" 
  [workspace]="workspace" 
  [removable]="true" 
  [selectable]="true" 
  [canAdd]="true" ]
  [editMode]="true" 
  (added)="tagAdded($event)" 
  (removed)="tagRemoved($event)"
> </mc-tags>

<!-- other components -->
<mc-tags [workspace]="workspace"></mc-tags>
```

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for this. So in my Edit Component, I import my Tags component like this                 <mc-tags [workspace]="workspace" [removable]="true" [selectable]="true" [canAdd]="true"
                    [editMode]="true" (added)="tagAdded($event)" (removed)="tagRemoved($event)">
                </mc-tags>

Comment: so I can just add getAllTags="true" inside that?

Comment: In other components I imported it like this  <mc-tags [workspace]="workspace"></mc-tags>

Comment: So there are multiple other inputs, just add `[getAllTags]="true"` along with others. I've edited the answer.

Comment: It work..Thank you so much for your help Michael. really appreciated it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use RxJS. You should keep your Tags Data in TagService as a Subject (observable). Btw it is always best practise to store data in service layer.

TagService:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TagService {

  tagsSource = new BehaviorSubject<Tag[]>(null);
  allnormalTags$ = this.tagsSource.asObservable();

  getAllTagsByType(type: string){
   http.request.subscribe(resultData => this.tagsSource.next(resultData))
   }

}
```

Then in your component you can check whether data are already loaded and don't call it again.

```
export class ProductListComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private tagService: TagService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (isNullOrUndefined(this.tagService.tagSource.getValue())
      this.tagService.getAllTagsByType('user')
  }
```

P.S. You don't need to explicitly subscribe service observable in your component. Instead you can directly get your data from service subject/observable with async pipe.

```
<table *ngIf="tagService.allnormalTags$ | async as allnormalTags">
 <tbody>
        <tr class="product-list-item" *ngFor="let tag of allnormalTags">
          <td data-label="name"> {{tag.name}} </td>
```